# Resolución de pantalla de fedora server con VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, fedora

tengo una duda, acabo de instalar Fedora server en una maquina virtual, pero, quiero saber como puedo aumentar la resolución de la pantalla de la maquina virtual para poder trabajar mejor con los datos de las base de datos que quiero instalar, ya que por el momento la resolución es muy poca para ver los datos, Saludos Geeks.[image: en la imagen se muestra lo pequeña que es la pantalla]

Comment: La respuesta correcta es la de Saúl. Sin embargo, también puedes usar un cliente SSH para conectarte. Personalmente me resulta más cómodo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que seguir una serie de procedimientos e instalar las Guest Additions y reiniciar una vez reiniciado se te debe re dimensionar
te dejo los pasos:

abres la terminar con privilegios de sudo:

```
sudo dnf update
sudo dnf upgrade
```

una vez terminado reinicias la maquina virtual

```
reboot
```

instalamos los siguientes paquetes

```
dnf install gcc kernel-devel kernel-headers dkms make bzip2 perl libxcrypt-compat
```

añadimos una variable al entorno del kernel

```
KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/`uname -r`
```

exportamos la variable

```
export KERN_DIR
```

ahora nos vamos a la barra de herramientas de virtualbox en dispositivos/**insertar imagen de las Guest Additions**

el paquete debería ejecutarse automáticamente, a continuación haga clic en ejecutar/run, le pedira la contraseña de sudo
una vez instalado deberia mostrar el siguiente mensaje:

```
virtualbox guest additions running kernel modules will not be replaced until the system is restarted
```

una vez terminado reiniciamos la maquina virtual

```
reboot
```

ya que haya reiniciado deberia de re dimensionar al tamaño de la ventana de virtualbox, te dejo las instrucciones mas detalladas en el siguiente enlace

[Como instalar las guest additions en fedora](https://www.fosslinux.com/25537/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-fedora.htm)

Comment: Procura incluir al menos un bosquejo de los pasos a seguir en tu respuesta. Si esa página cambia el SEO o apagan el sitio, el enlace se rompe y tu respuesta ya no le servirá a los demás.